# Why is my udev rule called twice?

Tags: services, udev, eject, cd

I am working on CentOS 7. I wrote a udev rule in order to start a service each time a cd is inserted.
The udev rule is the following :

```
KERNEL=="sr1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="change", ENV{ID_CROM_CD}=="1", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="1", RUN+="/bin/systemctl restart cd-mount@%k.service"
```

The service is configured as follow :

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount CD drive on %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cd-mount.sh %i
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/cd-mount.sh %i
```

For some reason my udev rule is called twice. This is pretty annoying since I am mounting the CD-ROM, I got errors because of that. How can I write my rule so it is called only once ?

EDIT : I have changed my udev rule and now the service is restarted only once. The udev rule looks like this :

```
KERNEL=="sr[0-1]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="change", ENV{ID_CROM_CD}=="1", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="udf" RUN+="/bin/systemctl restart cd-mount@%k.service"
```

There is one remaining problem. This rule detects that another CD is inserted only when the "eject" command is used. When I press the button eject, nothing happens. Does somebody know why ?

Comment: Are you sure it's the udev rule that is called twice? Or is it `cd-mount.sh`? `systemctl restart` means stop+start, so `ExecStop`+`ExecStart`, so (in your case) `cd-mount.sh` *twice*. If the rule was called twice, the script would run four times. Is this what happens?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes the script is run four times.